# Trying to add a subview, drawRect isn't called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, drawrect

I'm trying to add a subview to my main view. Here's the relevant code from my viewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MyUIViewSubclass* myView = [[MyUIViewSubclass alloc] init]; 
    [self.view addSubview:myView]; // self.view is a simple UIView
    [myView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

drawRect in myView doesn't get called.

However, if I use a MyUIViewSubclass as the main view for the viewController (setting it in Interface Builder), drawRect does get called.

What do I need to do to get drawRect called in my subView?

Comment: Ok, figured it out. Wasn't setting the bounds of my subView.

Comment: Actually, should be setting the bounds, not the frame. Works as expected now.

Comment: You should probably close this question then.

Answer (score 7):

In your subclass you should use the designated initialiser for UIView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
       //Implementation code...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to refresh the contents of my subclass? If I was just drawing it once, I would go ahead and use initWithFrame, but I need a way to have the subview redraw itself.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out. Wasn't setting the frame of my subView.

Comment: That's what I meant with using the designated initaliser :)